# org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, file-upload, neo4j

I'm building a little springboot app which make CRUD operations on Neo4j graph database. One of the action is bulk inserts with CSV file.

I'm getting these errors :
From chrome

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9090/neo4jtest/api/employees/upload-csv' from origin 'http://localhost:8090' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

Here is the controller (I delete useless mappings) :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @PostMapping("/upload-csv")
    public String uploadCSVFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, Model model) {

        // validate file
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Please select a CSV file to upload.");
            model.addAttribute("status", false);
        } else {
            // parse CSV file to create a list of `employee` objects
            try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))) {
                // create csv bean reader
                CsvToBean<Employee> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Employee>(reader).withType(Employee.class).withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true).build();
                // convert `CsvToBean` object to list of employees
                // TODO : save employees into neo4j
                // save employees list on model
                model.addAttribute("employees", Employees.builder().employeeList(csvToBean.parse()).build());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                model.addAttribute("message", "An error occurred while processing the CSV file.");
                model.addAttribute("status", false);
            }
        }   
        return "list";
    }
}
```

Here is the webpage using thymleaf template :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn-upload-csv").click(function() {
        $('#neo4j-filechooser').trigger('click');
    });

    $('#neo4j-filechooser').on('change', function() {
        myfiles = this.files; //save selected files to the array
        console.log(myfiles[0]); //show them on console
        formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file",myfiles[0])
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:9090/neo4jtest/api/employees/upload-csv",
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization"
            },
            data: formdata
        }).then(function(data) {
           $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
           $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
        });
    }).click();
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From your error stack trace it can be seen that the error is actually :

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

that is even though the content-type is set , the multi-part boundary is not getting set. So, **the problem is that you are setting the `Content-Type` by yourself**, let it be blank so that jquery will do it for you. The issue is actually in your request as per the specification :

> The Content-Type field for multipart entities requires one parameter,
>   "boundary", which is used to specify the encapsulation boundary. The
>   encapsulation boundary is defined as a line consisting entirely of two
>   hyphen characters ("-", decimal code 45) followed by the boundary
>   parameter value from the Content-Type header field.

In your jquery request , you are setting the `processData: false`,
and `contentType: false`, which forces jquery to set both the content-type and the boundary. But in the header section of request you are again manually adding `content-type`. Remove it from code and try. If it does not work, could you please share the sample data so that we could analyze it more. The issue could also happen if you are using an older version of jquery or running it from an older browser.

try the following code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn-upload-csv").click(function() {
        $('#neo4j-filechooser').trigger('click');
    });

    $('#neo4j-filechooser').on('change', function() {
        myfiles = this.files; //save selected files to the array
        console.log(myfiles[0]); //show them on console
        formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file",myfiles[0])
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:9090/neo4jtest/api/employees/upload-csv",
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization"
            },
            data: formdata
        }).then(function(data) {
           $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
           $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
        });
    }).click();
});
```